# How to use i18n on an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

In my application in Rails 4, I have something like this to construct a select in my view (I use Simple_form) :

```
<%= f.input :period, :collection => [['Yesterday', 1], ['Since 7 days', 2], ['Since 30 days', 3], ['Since forever', 4], ['Custom', 4]], :as => :radio_buttons %>
```

For information, the view and this input (select) aren't linked to a model.

For example, in French, I want to obtain this :

```
<%= f.input :period, :collection => [['Hier', 1], ['Depuis 7 jours', 2], ['Depuis 30 jours', 3], ['Depuis toujours', 4], ['Personnalisé', 4]], :as => :radio_buttons %>
```

What is the right syntax to write this array of arrays in locales file (.yml) and in the view ?

I tried several solutions but didn't find the good one...

Thanks